# PyQT: get recursive children of a widget

Tags: qt, pyqt

Anyone have a slick function that will return a nested tree of all the children of a particular widget?

I'm familiar with dumpObjectTree() but I'm not able to compile in debug mode, so I don't have access to that function.

Trying to find a particular widget and I'm traversing the children() hierarchy by hand.  There's got to be a better way!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[QObject.findChild](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChild) (or [findChildren](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qobject.html#findChildren)) will recursively search for a child and should do what you need.

Comment: My colleague has written a rather deep object tree (a MainWindow contains derived QGroupBox-es, which contain derived QGraphicsScene-s, etc...). Instead of going through the extra effort of naming things, then finding their names (recursively?), I'd rather just dump out the whole tree, to use it as a cheat sheet...

Comment: Something like:

    def dump(thing, depth=0):
        print '  ' * depth + repr(thing)
        for kid in thing.children():
            dump(kid, depth + 1)
            
    dump(self.mainWindow)

Answer (score 0):

I found that a `QObject` has a `dumpObjectTree` method at [this link](https://doc.qt.io/archives/qq/qq03-big-brother.html). Is that what you're looking for?